# active admin inputs block inside has_many in nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

In Active Admin I want to add image upload on an association on a model inside a nested form, using the method shown [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Nested-model-form-image-upload). The code doesn't cause any error, but when I load the form, the file upload section (the part using inputs inside the has_many), doesn't show up at all.  Code looks something like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

  f.inputs “My Model” do
    f.has_many :model_associations do |ma|
      ma.inputs “Image Upload” do |image|
        image.input :file, as: :file
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I wonder if the problem is that I have an inputs inside the `has_many`? Should I be able to have an inputs inside a `has_many`?

Comment: What is `f.has_many :model_associations`? And what do you mean, 'doesn't like'?

Comment: @jvillian :model_associations is just a random name I gave to illustrate that there's an association on "My Model".  "Doesn't like" means "isn't working" - the form doesn't render anything for the image upload section, not even the "Image Upload" text.  It seems to me like the ma.inputs block is being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't need this line at all:

```
ma.inputs 'Image Upload' do |image|
```

Just rewrite it like so:

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors(*f.object.errors.keys)

  f.inputs 'My Model' do
    f.has_many :model_associations do |i|
      i.input :file, as: :file
    end
  end

  f.actions
end
```